# Extracting hierachy structure into json

Tags: php, json

i am having trouble getting my mysql table into json.
I have a table that show the hierachy of employees like that:

The table is a employee table with
    id, firstname, lastname, parentid

So now I want to query through the data to extract it into a multi level json object to simulate show the employees with their supervisors.

I hope somebody can help me with it.

Comment: you are asking at least 3 questions in one. 1. whether to get data via mysql and work on it with php 2. how to iterate thorugh your results 3. how to convert php array/object into json (`json_encode()` btw.). Please clarify what you need, show us what you've tried thus far.

Comment: So I do not have any trouble using json_encode or doing simple or joint mysql querys.
So from the technicall side I have a basic understanding of all of the actions I need to do.

The problem is that I can't think of a way to query through the data so that I get the multidimensional array that I then can convert into json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've already taken data from the database, below solution will  get you what you need.

The way to go about it is via **recursion**.

[php sandbox online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b27d43ff7cd1e75196ed57402d658001165fd425)

```
<?php
function buildTree(array &$elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parentid'] == $parentId) {

            // recursion:
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[$element['id']] = $element;
            unset($elements[$element['id']]);
        }
    }
    return $branch;
}
$rows = [
    ['id' => 1, 'firstname' => 'john1', 'lastname' => 'doe', 'parentid' => 0],
    ['id' => 2, 'firstname' => 'john2', 'lastname' => 'doe', 'parentid' => 1],
    ['id' => 3, 'firstname' => 'john3', 'lastname' => 'doe', 'parentid' => 1],
    ['id' => 4, 'firstname' => 'john4', 'lastname' => 'doe', 'parentid' => 0],
    ['id' => 5, 'firstname' => 'john5', 'lastname' => 'doe', 'parentid' => 3],
];

print_r(buildTree($rows));
```

and the resulting array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [firstname] => john1
            [lastname] => doe
            [parentid] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [firstname] => john2
                            [lastname] => doe
                            [parentid] => 1
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [firstname] => john3
                            [lastname] => doe
                            [parentid] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 5
                                            [firstname] => john5
                                            [lastname] => doe
                                            [parentid] => 3
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [firstname] => john4
            [lastname] => doe
            [parentid] => 0
        )

)
```

After you `json_encode` the result, [you will get](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=51381d4cfd80ae23c7b5cb1ce61978b6):

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "john1",
        "lastname": "doe",
        "parentid": 0,
        "children": {
            "2": {
                "id": 2,
                "firstname": "john2",
                "lastname": "doe",
                "parentid": 1
            },
            "3": {
                "id": 3,
                "firstname": "john3",
                "lastname": "doe",
                "parentid": 1,
                "children": {
                    "5": {
                        "id": 5,
                        "firstname": "john5",
                        "lastname": "doe",
                        "parentid": 3
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "4": {
        "id": 4,
        "firstname": "john4",
        "lastname": "doe",
        "parentid": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. That is exactly what I have been looking for. I will try it later when I am back home.